# Auto refresh token when invalid in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, oauth-2.0, axios, jwt

I would like to know what methods there are to implement auto refresh invalid access token in React app. Every time making a request I want to:

1. Make a request
2. If 401 status/an error
3. Make a request to refresh access token
4. Make the initial request again

In my current project I'm using React/Redux and making requests via axios.

Answer (score 1):

For implementing refresh token via axios i recommand using interceptor.

what is interceptor ?

You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

in link below there is a good example of implementing refresh token in axios interceptor:

https://gist.github.com/Godofbrowser/bf118322301af3fc334437c683887c5f

Comment: Yeah, that works unless I want to use Apollo client for my data requests....